# Send TriggeredSend Email not configured correctly

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud

We tried to trigger a Triggered Email using client name and password external key using the following sample script:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/send_triggeredsend_email/.

This external key and mail template were configured using  other consumer account details. They have created one more test account and given all permission to trigger mail for the external key.

Then we try to trigger the email using test account, the external external key from other account configured mail template.

Is there any limitation in using the same account to trigger emails?  Can we use the other accounts to trigger the configured mail template?

Please help us this

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger an an email configured in one account with another account's credentials.  However, there's nothing stopping you from configuring a copy of a `Triggered Send Definition` in a different account -- even one with the same Customer/External Key.  The only difference would be the user credentials and possibly the endpoint (S1,S4,S6,S7).